# as modifier not working in (e.KeyCode == x as Keys) in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard

I'm having an error with this block of code in C#

```
    private void frm2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string x = "w";
        if (e.KeyCode == x as Keys)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
    }
```

I get this error

The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('System.Windows.Forms.Keys' is a non-nullable value type)

I need to do something similar to what this user posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726448/how-do-i-respond-to-a-specific-sequence-of-key-presses). I haven't a clue why this isn't working and would appreciate any help. I am relatively new to programming so please go easy on me. I would be willing to supply any other part of the code necessary to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Enum.Parse` method to convert string to `Keys` but I suggest you to use use `Keys.W`

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
{
        //do whatever
}
```

Your attempt doesn't work because `x` is of type string which can never be of type `Keys`. You cannot cast string to `Keys` enum, you can only `convert` it. Remember cast and convert are two different things.

If at all you need to convert here's how you do

```
string str = ...;//Get string somehow
Keys myKey = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof (Keys), str);
```

---

You can use keys to achieve the same with keys enum like this.

```
Keys neededLetter = Keys.W;
if (e.KeyCode == neededLetter)
{
    if ( neededLetter == Keys.N)
    {
        neededLetter =  Keys.O;
    } else if ( neededLetter == Keys.O ) {
        neededLetter = Keys.T;
    } else if ( neededLetter ==  Keys.T ) {
        neededLetter =  Keys.E;
    } else if ( neededLetter == Keys.E ) {
        // you now have the full sequence typed, show your app
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I need it to receive a certain specific sequence of key inputs, like the post I linked.

Comment: @user3288171 Updated the answer, check if that helps

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is a String to Enum conversion

```
if (e.Modifiers == (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "keys1", true) && e.KeyCode == (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "keys2", true))
        {
            string keyPressed = e.KeyCode.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(keyPressed);
        }
```

Example:

```
    private int count = 0;
    private string keysPressed = "NOTE";
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (count < keysPressed.Length)
        {
            if (e.Modifiers == (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "None", true) &&
                e.KeyCode == (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), keysPressed[count].ToString(), true))
            {
                if (count == keysPressed.Length - 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(keysPressed);
                    //restart
                    count = 0;
                }
                else
                    count++;
            }
            else
                count = 0;
        }
        else
            count = 0;
    }
```

Comment: what are "keys1" and "keys2" in this context?

Comment: your x variable, the name of the key pressed

Comment: Does it have to be a literal? or is it supposed to be the string

Comment: Has to be string. Update my answer, added an example.